JWT en .netCore 6.0 me reemplaza el Claim de Role por una URL
Estoy usando JWT en .netCore 6.0 , al momento de validar el role del usuario, me encuentro que el Claim.Type en lugar de ser "role", tal como lo configuré, se reemplaza por la url: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"
esto me genera problemas al querer evaluar el role del usuario desde el token.
Clase que genera el Token al loguearse
JWT.cs
using ApiUsuarios.Entidades;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

namespace ApiUsuarios.MiddleWares
{
    public class JWT
    {
        public static string GenerateJwtToken(Usuario usuario, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configuration["JwtSettings:SecretKey"]);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim("id", usuario.Id.ToString()),
                    new Claim("usuario", usuario.Email),
                    new Claim("role", usuario.Rol.Nombre)
                    
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
}

Ejemplo de un método en el controlador donde solicito que el usuario esté identificado y deba tener el rol de Admin.
[HttpDelete("BorradoSuave/{Id:int}")]
        [Authorize]

        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteSuave(int Id)
        {
            var usuario = await _context.Usuarios.AsTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == Id);
            if (usuario is null)
            {
                return NotFound("No se encontró usuario para borrar");

            }
            // Validar si el usuario autenticado tiene el rol "Admin"
            var claims = HttpContext.User.Claims;
    
            var isAdmin = claims.Any(c => c.Type == "role"  && c.Value== "Admin");

            if (!isAdmin)
            {
                return Unauthorized("Acceso no autorizado");
            }
            usuario.Borrado = 1; 
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok("Usuario borrado");
        }

Haciendo un debug del código, con puntos de interrupción ,pude ver lo que les comento arriba.
Agradezco su ayuda.

Al momento de generar el token, en vez de role, dale userRole y realiza los cambios respectivos. Sucede que hay un estándar con respecto a JWT, roles, subject y demás. Saludos.

@fredyfx EXCELENTE! Agradezco mucho tu ayudo, funcionó a la primera.

Venga, vamos, con todo el power 2.0!!! Lo pondré a modo de respuesta. Márcala como aceptada, cosa que colaboramos con la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos.

Algo simple, reemplaza:
new Claim("role", usuario.Rol.Nombre)

Por:
new Claim("userRole", usuario.Rol.Nombre)

Y realiza los cambios respectivos. Sucede que hay un estándar con respecto a JWT, roles, subject y demás. Saludos.

Muchas gracias @fredyfx.

Un gusto colaborar, sigue progresando :D

var usuario = _da_usuario.ValidarUsuario(_usuario.NombreUsuario, _usuario.Contraseña);

if (usuario != null)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, usuario.NombreUsuario),
        new Claim("contraseña", usuario.Contraseña),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, usuario.DescripcionRol),
        new Claim("descripcionArea", usuario.DescripcionArea)
    };

    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));

    TempData["Area"] = usuario.DescripcionArea;

    if (usuario.DescripcionRol.Equals("Administrador") || usuario.DescripcionRol.Equals("Director"))
    {
        // Redirige a la acción Index del controlador Solicitud, pasando el área como parámetro en la URL
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Solicitud", new { area = usuario.DescripcionArea });
    }
    else if (usuario.DescripcionRol.Equals("Capturista"))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Create", "Solicitud");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
else
{
    return View("/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
}

